# Correct typo error in the article title that published Early Access of the journal

Tags: publications, publishers, errors-erratum

I have a accepted  article that published under early Access.

Today, I have got the proofs from the journal to approve some changes. I have found a typo error in the title "Commutation" instead of "Communication". I have already sign the copyright form that contains the paper title.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Make your changes in the proofs, or at least tell the journal what changes to make. From what you describe, "Early Access" means the paper hasn't been published yet; the journal just put whatever was accepted onto their webpage. In that case the proofs are your chance to make changes - this is also the most convenient time for them.

Comment: I agree and at the same time, I would just like to add from my experience that such "minor" corrections tend to be ignored by the journal staff (despite being returned well within the time for proof corrections). Guess this heavily depends on the actual publishing house and journal.